# Meteor Files findOne return undefined

Tags: reactjs, meteor

i use [Meteor Files](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files) for uploading files. i managed to save it to database and filesystem but i failed to get those files from its `findOne` method. here is my product collection :

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import Images from './imagesCollection';


const ProductCollection = new Mongo.Collection( 'products' );

ProductCollection.helpers({
   photos() {
      return Images.findOne({ meta: { productId: this._id } });
   }
});
```

and here is my image collection:

```
const Images = new FilesCollection({
collectionName: 'Images',
allowClientCode: false,
storagePath: () => {
    return `${process.env.PWD}/public/assets/products/`;
},
onBeforeUpload: function(file) {
    if (/png|jpe?g/i.test(file.extension)) {
        return true;
    }

  }

});


export default Images;
```

i used [meteor-collection-helper](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-collection-helpers) to get image associated with the product.

```
class ProductBox extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.productRemove = this.productRemove.bind(this);
    this.selectUpdate = this.selectUpdate.bind(this);
}

render() {
    console.log(this.props.produk.photos())
    return (
    );
  }
}

export default ProductBox;
```

whenever i consol log out the image collection it returned undefined or the cursor failed to get the data. please point me out which part i'm doing it wrong? any help would be appreaciated!

Comment: Have you read on their wiki [about collection instances](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/wiki/Collection-Instances)?

Comment: i have but i don't really understand how to use it or why should i use it? i follow the documentation but i failed to get the cursor

Comment: So you also tried using `return Images.collection.findOne` and got no document?